# English name of "Verde Doncella" (Spanish) apple cultivar

Tags: identification, apples, cultivar

"[Verde Doncella](https://www.ecured.cu/Verde_doncella_(Manzana))" is the Spanish name of an apple cultivar [typical of Aragon](http://tienda.agrologica.es/comprar-planta-vivero-frutales/492-manzano-verde-doncella.html). Does it have a different name in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has the same name in English. Verde Doncella. It is a Spanish cultivar, so the Spanish name of the cultivar is also used in other countries. In the Netherlands for instance we also have apple cultivars with English names, such as "Golden Delicious" and "Granny Smith", we don't change them to Dutch names.